# RegEx for extracting a decimal number

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a pandas df where a column is a text with ratings in a format of X/10. I want to extract the numerators (which can be decimals). So far I was using:

```
my_df.text_column.str.extract('(\d*?\.?\d+(?=/10))')
```

I thought I was doing fine until I saw that I had some numerators like `.10`. What is actually happening is some rows have text like: "Nice job.10/10".

How can I specify that when extracting a number from this column, in case it detected a "." it must have came after a digit?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to extract the numerator as .10 or 10?

Comment: In that example, as 10. In case I have "0.10/10", then it would be "0.10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
df.text.str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d*?(?=/10))')
```

You want to first look for a number (`\d+`) followed by an optional (`\.?`) and an optional decimal (`\d*?`)

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["Nice Job.10/10", "Score 9.5/10", "And now 5./10"]})
df.text.str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d*?(?=/10))')



    0
0   10
1   9.5
2   5.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the numerator pattern into two cases: one with "." and one without ".".

- Numerator with ".": `\d+\.\d+`
- Numerator without ".": `\d+`

Thus, the pattern for the numerator would be `(\d+\.\d+|\d+)`.
Putting everything together, we have `(\d+\.\d+|\d+)/\d+`.

The order of two parts matter if the regexp engine does not prioritize longer matches. Putting the longer alternative first will give you the longest match. If the numerator is a decimal number, the whole numerator (`\d+\.\d+`) is chosen instead of just the decimal part (`\d+`).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way `(\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?=/10))`

---

Sample

```
Nice job.10/10".
 "0.10/10", then it would be "0.10"
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?=/10))
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    1.04 s,   1038.38 ms,   1038383 µs
Matches per sec:   96,303
```